# Android Studio - debugger not working on android device despite working on emulator

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, debugging

I am working in Android 2.2.3 on my MacBook Pro (early 2011/Sierra-10.12.2).

When I am debugging my app using the emulator (Nexus 5 API 25) it works perfectly fine. As soon as I am debugging on a real Android device, my Honor 5X (Android 6.0.1, API 23) the debugger does not attach (i.e. it does not stop at the breaking points). Strangely enough I am not receiving any errors/warnings (neither in the event log nor in the android monitor, nor in the gradle console) letting me know what I need to do in order to fix it.

As suggested in previous related questions on SO, I have tried...

- restarting Android Studio
- disabling ADB Integration and enabling it again
- disconnecting my device and reconnecting it again
- adding debuggable flag in AndroidManifest.xml

...but nothing worked so far. I am relatively new to Android Studio, can anybody help me out?